# Assign unique tokens to each node in a DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes

I've got a set of tokens that I need to distribute to each pod in a DaemonSet.   The tokens can't be generated at run time but were generated ahead of time.

This sort of distribution is easy to do with StatefulSets -- it could be done with a volumeClaimTemplate, but the mechanism I'm currently using is to store all the tokens in a single secret and then I grab the suffix from the pod name to choose which token to read.

However StatefulSets trigger the cluster autoscaler.   If I use anti-affinity to ensure that there is only one pod per node, and then set the number of replicas to the maximum number of nodes in cluster, it will cause the cluster autoscaler to scale up to the maximum number of nodes and stay there.

A DaemonSet is the better model for what I'm trying to do (one pod per node) which is why I phrased the question the way I did, but a solution using StatefulSets or anything else would also be accepted.

Comment: Have you considered an `initContainer:` that does whatever calculation you wish and emits the token to an `emptyDir: {}` volume shared between it and the main `container:`?

Comment: the token is a pre-shared secret, it cannot be created via a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl annotate secret foo --resource-version=X --overwrite` can be used as a locking mechanism.   Read the annotation, determine if it's available, then annotate if it's available.   If your annotation succeeds you have the lock.   If it doesn't try a different secret.

Here's the script I wrote to do so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e -u -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit
#set -x

## START CONFIGURATION

KUBECTL="kubectl --context green -n foo"
ANNOTATION=foo
VALUE=node/$HOSTNAME

# returns in OBJECTS and VALID_VALUES constants
function readValues() {
    # this order is important.   The reverse will have a race condition
    OBJECTS=$($KUBECTL get secrets -l locktest=1 -o json | jq -r ".items[] | @base64")
    # read -p "Press enter to give chance to fake a race condition"
    VALID_VALUES=$($KUBECTL get nodes -o name)
}

## END CONFIGURATION

# returns via stdout kind/name of locked object
# returns via $?: 0 found, 1 not found
function isLockedAlready() {
    for obj in $OBJECTS; do
        json=$(echo "$obj" | base64 -d)
        value=$(echo $json | jq -r ".metadata.annotations.${ANNOTATION}")
        if [[ $value == $VALUE ]] ; then
            # echo $name is already locked
            name=$(echo "$json" | jq -r ".metadata.name")
            kind=$(echo "$json" | jq -r ".kind")
            echo $kind/$name
            return  0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

# returns via stdout the base64 json of an object that's not in listValidValues
# returns via $?: 0 found, 1 not found
function findCandidate() {
    for obj in $OBJECTS; do
        json=$(echo "$obj" | base64 -d)
        value=$(echo $json | jq -r ".metadata.annotations.${ANNOTATION}")
        name=$(echo $json | jq -r ".metadata.name")
        valid=0
        for v in $VALID_VALUES ; do
            if [[ $value == $v ]] ; then
                # echo $name has valid value $v
                valid=1
                # else # echo $name value $value is not $v
            fi
        done
        if [[ $valid == 0 ]]; then
            # echo $name is available
            echo $obj
            return 0
            # else # echo $name is not available
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

# $1: the object to lock (as base64 json)
# return in $?:  0==success
function lock() {
    name=$(echo "$1" | base64 -d | jq -r ".metadata.name")
    kind=$(echo "$1" | base64 -d | jq -r ".kind")
    resource_version=$(echo "$1" | base64 -d | jq -r ".metadata.resourceVersion")
    if $KUBECTL annotate $kind $name $ANNOTATION=$VALUE --resource-version=$resource_version --overwrite > /dev/null; then
        echo $kind/$name
        return 0
    else
        # echo "ANNOTATION FAILED!  RETRY"
        return 1
    fi
}

for retry in 1 2 3 ; do
    readValues
    if isLockedAlready ; then
        exit 0
    elif obj=$(findCandidate) ; then
        if lock "$obj" ; then
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
    sleep 20
    # echo retry
done

exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an autoscaler messing with you, using a StatefulSet with anti-affinity set up to get one pod per node is an easier solution by far.   Just use volumeClaimTemplates and then put the tokens in the subsequent volumes.

Or if the tokens are in secrets, then you can mount all of the secrets in each pod, and then grab the number from the end of `$POD_NAME` to know which secret to actually use.